# Urllib2 is somehow changing my post data on send

Tags: python, request, http-post, urllib2

I'm trying to make a POST request to a server. However, when making this post, the data gets messed up somewhere along the way.

My Code:

```
headers = {"Context-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
           "Authorization" : "Basic user pass"
values = {"query" : "select", "table" : "testtable"}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.request(url, data, headers = headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print res.result()
```

However, I noticed that the "data" is somehow changed. It should (and does when I print it) look something like

```
query=select&table=testtable
```

However, when I actually do a post request, this site registers:

```
<parameter id="&#13;&#10query">select</parameter>
<parameter id="table">testtab</parameter>
```

So it looks like the data is somehow shifted over 2 spaces. This is indepenedent of where I do the post request. Anyone ever have an error like this?

Answer (score 0):

[It sounds like](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) your original data has a carriage return (`'\r'`) and line feed (`'\n'`) in it (the `'&#13;'` and `'&#10;'`). So, it might look like your key name is `'query'`, but you probably have some extra characters hidden in there.

Your site should use `urlparse.parse_qs` to read the request data. By default, that function will ignore those two characters:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> data = '&#13;&#10;query=select&table=testtable'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(data)
'query': ['select'], 'table': ['testtable']}
>>> # make the parsing strict:
... urlparse.parse_qs(data, strict_parsing=True)
ValueError: bad query field: ''
```

So, those two characters are ignored if you use the default parameters with `urlparse.parse_qs`. Best solution is to check your input and get rid of those characters.

Comment: My input are strings created by the program, they don't contain those two symbols. Also, when I print request.get_data(), it shows the correct string:
    query=select&table=testtable

Comment: Then it sounds like your site's code is not reading the data correctly. Can you post the code that receives and processes the POST request?

Comment: I do not control the server, and the same effect has happened on multiple and completely independent servers.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm out of ideas. Maybe someone else who reads this question will have some thoughts.